# OpenGL rendering from Windows Service

Tags: c#, opengl, service, rendering

I'm trying to do some openGL rendering from a windows service.  I recently discovered however that this is not supported and services do not have access to the GPU.  I was wondering if there were any workarounds to get access to the GPU from a service.

I've done some research on the matter but have yet to find any solutions.  Some recommendations were to spin off another application from the service which would do the rendering, but in that case as far as I'm aware a user would need to be logged in.  Is there anyway to do this without someone being logged in?

I also read that Nvidia released drivers to allow some communication with their Tesla series.  We're using Intel HD Graphics 3000 and I have yet to find anything that seems to support service rendering with the Intel card.

Comment: I believe your problem is due to the fact that non-interactive services run in "Session 0", which has limited access to graphics hardware beginning in Windows Vista. There is a setting: "Allow Service to interact with desktop" that will move your service to a different session (still without a user login) that ***may*** allow you to interact with the GPU. See [here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687105(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: What Adnon M. Coleman said. Also you'll have to use a PBuffer or a FBO.